# Unity - files .txt in Project are hidden into the .apk?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, project

If I have a .txt file in a project folder of an Android project and I build this project as .apk. This file is accessible for the user from the Device Explorer or in hidden into the .apk?

(I apologize for my english)

Comment: I think it is inside the APK, by the way that doesn't mean it will be secured... You can check it by just making an APK of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also access the streamingAssetsPath (read only):
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

and the persistentDataPath (this is a folder where you can read/write data, accessible to your users... but you can access this folder only after the installation):
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

To read files in the streamingAssets on Android you need to use WWW class but everything is explained in the docs (with an example).

Read this to understand if you really need to use Resources folder or it's better to use streamingAssetsPath:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder

if you want to undestand the difference I suggest to read this:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/resources-vs-streamingassets-for-mobile.494804/

Comment: thank you so much this response was really thorough and detailed, I could not have wished for better

Comment: if you really like the answer the best way is to accept it so that everyone that got the same problem know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Unity will produce a `.apk`-file.

Your `.txt`-file will be baked in if:

- Its referenced by something in the scene
- Its in the `Resources` folder

Comment: thank you, it was just the answer I was looking for 